# S3 put operation without APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to build an application using no-code platforms (bubble.io-> it allows you to build a website without writing a single line of code ). It will include an image upload part and I am using AWS s3 as the storage. Is there any way I can securely upload images/files to s3 without writing any APIs? If possible, please share the method and s3 bucket policy

Thank you

Comment: What is " no-code platforms"?

Comment: does the unnamed no-code platform offer such capability?

Comment: Hi, no code -> I used bubble.io/Appgyver. These platforms support s3 upload using plugins but those are not free. but I can use rest endpoints to connect with any other APIs. so I was trying if s3 allows us to upload files using rest API(i mean any default API end points), that will be easier and cost effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small note before I answer:

> AWS is just compute resources made available through a REST API. All the SDKs (NodeJS, Java, Go etc.) and tools (Terraform, Pulumi, etc.) are just thin wrappers around this REST API.

Therefore, there is a REST API endpoint for S3 you can use to "put objects" into a bucket:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

But you are probably going to have a bad time using the API in a "no code" environment, because there are just things that need some code. For example: if you have to sign your request (for authentication purposes). Then I hope your "no code" platform provides all the required tools to do something like this.

In the end you will need either to pay them for their addons (which is probably the business model) or do a lot of work yourself.